# DIV is floating on the page

Tags: html, css

this is a part of the whole html of the page. My problem is: this div named "blocos" is floating on top of another p elements when I put it on the main page. The other p elements don't have any float or position properties. What I am missing? Thanks in advance.

My HTML:

```
<div class="blocos">  
      <div class="gradient clicavel">
        <p>Bloco 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="conteudo esconde" style="display: none;">
        <p><strong>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet  doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. </strong></p><p>Typi non habent  claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem.  Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt  saepius. é çã o</p><p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem  consuetudium lectorum. </p><ul><li>Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc  putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per  seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br></li><li>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis  videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</li></ul>
      </div>

      <div class="gradient clicavel">
        <p>Bloco 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="conteudo " style="display: none;">
        <p><strong>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet  doming id quod azim placerat facer possim assum. </strong></p><p>Typi non habent  claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem.  Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt  saepius. é çã o</p><p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem  consuetudium lectorum. </p><p>&nbsp;</p><ul><li>Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc  putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per  seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br></li><li>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis  videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</li></ul>
      </div>

      <div class="gradient clicado">
        <p>Bloco 3</p>
      </div>
      <div class="conteudo " style="display: block;">
        <p><strong>Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet  doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. </strong></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Typi non habent  claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem.  Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt  saepius. </p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>Claritas est etiam processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem  consuetudium lectorum. </p><p>&nbsp;</p><ul><li>Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc  putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas humanitatis per  seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. <br></li><li>Eodem modo typi, qui nunc nobis  videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes in futurum.</li></ul>
      </div>

</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.clicado {
  width: 114px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4!important;
  color: black;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.clicavel {
  width: 114px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
.blocos div p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Calibre Medium";
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  margin: 0;
}
.esconde {
  display: block !important;
}
.conteudo {
  display: none;
  min-height: 318px;
  width: 601px;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  color: #747474;
  font-family: "Calibre Medium";
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}
.conteudo p:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

Comment: The code you posted looks fine http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/6urer9yj/. If anything, try adding `overflow:auto` to `.blocos`.

Comment: Probably forgot to clear the floats?